# MMC > Certificates > Other computers: Which firewall ports used for this?

Tags: port, windows-firewall, ad-certificate-services

I am having a windows firewall issue when trying to access the Certificate Store from another computer on the same domain using MMC or PowerShell. I am logged in as a domain admin. Both servers are windows server 2019.

If I disable windows firewall on the remote computer I can successfully add the snap-in and see the certificates. If I enable the firewall I cannot connect.

[image]

I am doing a installation of Service Fabric that comes with a pre-installation check script that also fails with an related error. It cannot access the remote certification store. If I disable the firewall this scripts also runs with success.

[image]

If I disable the firewalls the test succeeds.

[image]

Anyone knows the firewalls requirements for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was these rules that needed to be enabled

[image]